# Good designing of gRPC status and response

Tags: grpc

As a server side who provide gRPC API of calling some services, **which is the reasonable way to return the service have succeed or not?**

#### Case 1. Return as a Response

The server returns success or failure as a response message.

```cpp
// message Succeed{ bool value = 1; }
// rpc DoJob(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (Succeed) {}

Status Impl::DoJob(ServerContext* context, 
  const Empty* request, Succeed* response) {

  bool success = service_.job();
  response->set_value(success);

  return Status::OK;
}
```

#### Case 2. Return as a Status Code

The server returns success or failure as a status code.

```cpp
// rpc DoJob(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}

Status Impl::DoJob(ServerContext* context, 
  const Empty* request, Empty* response) {

  bool success = service_.job();

  if (success) return Status::OK
  return Status::CANCELLED;
}
```

As a client using the gRPC API, which case is easier to understand? Should Status code only indicate network status? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status is intended to be used by services to communicate error or success.

gRPC uses a single combined status for network and service errors to simplify error handling on the client-side. If your service returns `UNAVAILABLE` because one of its dependencies is down, the client will treat that the same as `UNAVAILABLE` because your service is down (which is a dependency of the client).

Some of the status codes are even [reserved for services](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/statuscodes.md) to use:

- INVALID_ARGUMENT
- NOT_FOUND
- ALREADY_EXISTS
- FAILED_PRECONDITION
- ABORTED
- OUT_OF_RANGE
- DATA_LOSS